# How to execute MariaDB stored procedure from azure data factory?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I wanted to 'Call' MariaDB Procedure from Azure Data Factory.

How can this be achieved, are there any other service which can be integrated with ADF to call this MariaDB procedures

I tried calling the procedure by writing the query using lookup activity.

It fails while showing this error.
ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: columns'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: columns,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

Comment: What activity is performed in stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup activity reads and returns the content of the query. I tried to repro this by creating three stored procedures in Azure SQL database for Maria DB.

First Stored procedure is written to update the data in the table.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_inventory()
BEGIN
  UPDATE inventory SET quantity = 150 
  WHERE id = 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When this procedure is called in ADF lookup activity, error occurs.

Second stored procedure is written with select query.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE select_inventory()
BEGIN
 select * from inventory;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When this SP is called, ADF pipeline is executed successfully.

In order to execute the stored procedure with update statements (or any statements), a select statement is added in the Stored procedure.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_select_inventory()
BEGIN
  UPDATE inventory SET quantity = 150 
  WHERE id = 1;
  select * from inventory;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When this stored procedure is called through Lookup activity, it got executed successfully.

[image]

[image]

**Try adding select statement in the stored procedure and execute it in Lookup activity. Or add Select statement after Call stored procedure statement.**

Comment: Yes, I added Select statement and the lookup activity is executing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

By selecting the 'query' option, you can call the stored procedure using lookup activity. From your error message, it looks like you are missing the parameter columns while calling the stored procedure.

Did you try executing the same code using the client tools like MySQL workbench? If you can execute the stored proc from other client tools, then you should be able to execute the same using the lookup activity.

I tested from my end and was able to execute the Stored procedure using lookup activity. Please see the below screenshot for your reference.

[image: Lookup]

[image: output]

[image: mysqlqworkbench]